# Scala: Replacing double quotes with single quotes

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, double-quotes, single-quotes

How do you replace single quotes with double quotes in Scala? I have a data file that has some records with "abc" (double quotes). I need to replace these quotes with single quotes and convert it to a data frame.

```
val customSchema_1 =        
  StructType(Array(
  StructField("ID", StringType, true),
  StructField("KEY", StringType, true),
  StructField("CODE", StringType, true))

val df_1 = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("delimiter", "¦")
  .schema(customSchema_1)
  .load("example")
```

Comment: which column have double quotes? what is your spark version ?

Comment: I am using spark core 1.6.0. The data in quotes is scattered throughout some data has quotes in the column while others don't.

Comment: This sounds like a problem that might be easier to solve with a bash script but you will basically need to write a regex which will find all double quotes within double quotes (for your column string) and replace them with single quotes

Comment: Here is an example using sed: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236154/shell-script-to-remove-double-quotes-within-the-column-value

Answer (score 4):

Read line by line your file and apply following example to each of them:

```
val text: String = """Here is a lot of text and "quotes" so you may think that everything is ok until you see something "special" or "weird"
"""

text.replaceAll("\"", "'")
```

This will give you a new String value with quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! How can you implement this if you are using a data frame? Is there a function in a data frame, which can allow this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple udf to replace double quote with single quote

Here is a simple example

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val removeDoubleQuotes = udf( (x:String) => s.replace("\"","'"))

//If df is the dataframe and use the udf to colName to replace " with '

df.withColumn("colName", removeDoubleQuotes($"colName"))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How to do this same thing in PySpark, especially `val removeDoubleQuotes = udf( (x:String) => s.replace("\"","'"))`